# Rational Team Concert: Merging only selected work items from a stream to its child.

Tags: version-control, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

We are planning to create a child stream(for each major release, at the time of release) from the integration stream and continue to use the child stream for that particular release.

Say, we've created this child stream on 1st Feb 2013. Development continues on the integration stream and nothing is delivered into the child stream. So, from 1st Feb to 30th April we deliver several work items to the integration stream and some of the work items are identified as changes that needs to go to the child stream as well. All such work items will be marked with a specific tag.

Now, is there a way to deliver only the change sets associated with these work-items into the child stream from the integration stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to deliver only the change sets associated with these work-items into the child stream from the integration stream.

Not easily, especially considering that delivering some change sets and not other is likely to end with a gap in the history of those files (and they are not [easy to find](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/103103/how-do-you-find-missing-changesets-if-there-is-a-gap-in-the-timeline)).

What you can do is select change sets listed in those work items, and select **`New -> Patch`** from the context menu.
You will transform those change sets in patches that you can apply anywhere you want.

[image: new patch]

The trick is to manage to list all change sets from WI with a specific tag

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain more about "You will transform those change sets in patches that you can apply anywhere you want." If my understanding is right, we need to first create a patch with all the required change sets, and then apply this patch in the maintenance stream. What is the procedure to apply the patch on the maintenance stream?

Comment: @Varun if you see a change set, you can right-click on it and make a path out of it. Then you can apply that patch in your local workspace. You need to make patches from the oldest change set to the newest.

Comment: Do I need to create a separate patch for each change set? I was thinking they will be a view where I can select all the change sets and create a single patch out of them. Is that not possible?

Comment: @Varun you *should* be able to select multiple change set (those listed in a Work Item for instance), and right-click on that multiple selection, in order to make *one* patch.